# Gson - deserialize json with nested map

Tags: json, gson

I am trying to deserialize this type of json

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "list": [
      {
        "000000": {
          "date": "2015-07-10 14:29:15"
        }
      },
      {
        "111111": {
          "date": "2015-07-11 14:29:15"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I manage to get a list inside my embedded object but the list entries are empty.

My Embedded class looks like this

```
public class Embedded {

    @SerializedName("list")
    private List<ListEntry> entries;
}
```

But I am not able to deserialize the list's entries. I think the problem is the fact that the map is nested inside an object that doesn't have a name.

```
public class ListEntry {

    private Map<String, ListEntryInfo> map;
}
```

Comment: I slightly missed a key point of your problem. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial problem is the way you declared your hierarchy. A `ListEntry` is a `Map<String, ListEntryInfo>` but does not have a `Map<String, ListEntryInfo>`. To make it work you have three options:

- declare the `ListEntry` class as `class ListEntry extends HashMap<String, ListEntryInfo> {}`, which is a bad idea in my opinion
- get rid of the `ListEntry` class and declare the `entries` list like this `@SerializedName("list") List<Map<String, ListEntryInfo>> entries;`
- use the approach I initially described below, by implementing a custom deserializer

---

As said before what you could do is to write a custom deserializer, so that you have a more typed list of entries.

As a `ListEntry` instance has only one `ListEntryInfo` value mapped to a key, I would change the structure to this:

```
class ListEntry {
    private String key;
    private ListEntryInfo value;

    public ListEntry(String key, ListEntryInfo value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return key + " -> " + value;
    }
}

class ListEntryInfo {
    //assuming we store the date as a String for simplicity
    @SerializedName("date")
    private String date;

    public ListEntryInfo(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Now you need to write a deserializer to create a new `ListEntry` instance when you deserialize the JSON:

```
class ListEntryDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ListEntry> {
    @Override
    public ListEntry deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> ite = json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator();
        //you may want to throw a custom exception or return an "empty" instance there
        Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = ite.next();
        return new ListEntry(entry.getKey(), context.deserialize(entry.getValue(), ListEntryInfo.class));
    }
}
```

This deserializer will read each `ListEntry`. As it's composed of a single key-value pair (in the first case the String "000000" is mapped to one `ListEntryInfo` and so on), we fetch the key and deserialize the corresponding `ListEntryInfo` with `JsonDeserializationContext` instance.

The final step, is to register it within the parser:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ListEntry.class, new ListEntryDeserializer()).create();
```

Running it on your example, you should get:

```
[000000 -> 2015-07-10 14:29:15, 111111 -> 2015-07-11 14:29:15]
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. I ended up using the second solution. I had previously managed to resolve the problem with a custom deserializer, but I am using retrofit so that meant that I had to parse myself the network response